# Swift how to format a large number with thousands separators?

Tags: swift

Is there a simple command to format 1.60543e+06 to 1,605,436???

resultFV.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%f", fv)

does not get it.

Comment: if your number fits in a `float`, it's not even remotely large!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Swift  Xcode 6.3, SOLVED (I decided to leave the $ in the code). If you don't want a $ in the output, change .CurrencyStyle  to .DecimalStyle

```
var fv = 3534234.55 
var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0;
resultFV.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(fv) // result: $3,534,235 –
```

Answer (score 41):

In Swift 3,

```
NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: NSNumber(value: whatever), number: NumberFormatter.Style.decimal)
```

Comment: You deserve more credit than you've gotten for this. I was trying to find this simple of an answer for a long time and no one seemed to have it until I found this.

Answer (score 23):

You should use a `NumberFormatter` for that:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal

resultFV.text = numberFormatter.string(from: fv)
```

Answer (score 11):

Update for Swift 4.1 currency string:

```
let balance = 1234567

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

let result = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: balance)) 
// result: $1,234,567
```

You can change `formatter.numberStyle` to `.decimal` to leave it as number without "$" sign.

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve this by using String initializers in Swift 3+:

```
// 1605436
let value: Int = 1605436

// "1,605,436" where Locale == en_US
let formattedInt = String(format: "%d", locale: Locale.current, value) 

// "1,605,436" where Locale == en_US
let formattedDouble = String(format: "%.0f", locale: Locale.current, Double(value))
```

Answer (score 5):

Update for Swift 5

````
var unformattedValue : Double = 3534234.55
var formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency // or .decimal if desired
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2; //change as desired
formatter.locale = Locale.current // or = Locale(identifier: "de_DE"), more locale identifier codes: https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273
var displayValue : String = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: unformattedValue))! // displayValue: "$3,534,235" ```
````

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you limit the precision, like `".0f"`

```
resultFV.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%.0f", fv)
```

**Updated Answer:**

```
var formatter: NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle;
var formattedStr: NSString = formatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: fv))!
resultFV.text = formattedStr
```

Comment: is nice, but I desire the commas for the thousands separators, like 1,123,456

Comment: ok see my fix above??? How do I format to my code looks like code like you have? thank you

Comment: I guess i already did what you want, you've to use `NSNumberFormatter` and get the string, then set it to label. Or you can directly assign to your label like `resultFV.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: fv))!`

Comment: ok see my fix above??? How do I format to my code looks like code like you have? thank you  Yours did not work in my xCode 6.3 Swift language, but the code above I posted does, but has a $. If Desire no $ then use as you did the .DecimalStyle :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated

Using Data Formatting available in `Foundation` for macOS 12.0+, iOS 15.0+, tvOS 15.0+, and watchOS 8.0+.

```
  let number: Int = 1000  
  let formatted = number.formatted(.number.grouping(.never))  
  print(formatted)
```

console output: `"1000"`

`number` can be any `BinaryFloatingPoint` or `BinaryInteger`