# Adding comma separator with NSNumber formatter

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

```
var primBreed = Double(Int(eggMulYearTextField.text!)!)
    primBreed = dblAnnProd / primBreed
    primBreedLabel.text = String(format:"%.2f", primBreed) 
  // Result:282258.26 Desired result: 282,258.26
```

Trying a different question about the use of NSNumber formatter..
I made progress and was able to partially format my result obtaining decimal, I am looking for the correct way to use NSNumber formatter to add comma separators.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999024/adding-thousand-separator-to-int-in-swift, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936474/swift-how-to-format-a-large-number-with-thousands-seperators